# How to check what lfs files are going to be uploaded?

Tags: git

when I try to push to remote I see that 69 lfs files are going to be uploaded.

How to check what are these files? Because have not done changes in any of lfs files

So, question is - how to check what exactly are going to be uploaded?

Comment: A commit is a snapshot of all files in a repo. So a push will contain all files no matter if they have been changed.

Answer (score 0):

Run git status to see which files will be included.

```
git status
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command from [git lfs](https://git-lfs.github.com/):

```sh
git lfs status
```

This command is described at this [github page](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/blob/master/docs/man/git-lfs-status.1.ronn):

> Display paths of Git LFS objects that
>
> - have not been pushed to the Git LFS server. These are large files that would be uploaded by git push.
> - have differences between the index file and the current HEAD commit. These are large
>   files that would be committed by git commit.
> - have differences between the working tree and the index file. These are files that could be staged using git add.
>
> This command must be run in a non-bare repository.